# Android programmatically automated touch events

Tags: android, automated-tests

I was wondering if there is any way to progam automated touch events? For example, I have my android app and I want to make a program where automatically make 100 tests and every test makes touch events depending on what appears on the app. And I would like to do this on emulators, if is possible all 100 test at the same time.

Comment: Try [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for exercising your app with many (more than 100 events) use `monkey` (Full name: UI/Application Exerciser Monkey) or/and `monkeyrunner`.

> The Monkey is a command-line tool that you can run on any emulator
>   instance or on a device. It sends a pseudo-random stream of user
>   events into the system, which acts as a stress test on the application
>   software you are developing.
>
> The Monkey includes a number of options, but they break down into four
>   primary categories:
>
> Basic configuration options, such as setting the number of events to
>   attempt.
>
> - Operational constraints, such as restricting the test to a single    package.
> - Event types and frequencies.
> - Debugging options.

Site: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/monkey.html

Basic using:

`$ adb shell monkey [options] <event-count>`

Example

`adb shell monkey -p your.package.name -v 500`

So if you want to take control over Android system events and you're familiar with Python and writing testing scripts, then you can use `monkeyrunner`.

> The monkeyrunner tool provides an API for writing programs that control an Android device or emulator from outside of Android code.
>
> With monkeyrunner, you can write a Python program that installs an Android application or test package, runs it, sends keystrokes to it, takes screenshots of its user interface, and stores screenshots on the workstation.
>
> The monkeyrunner tool is primarily designed to test applications and devices at the functional/framework level and for running unit test suites, but you are free to use it for other purposes.

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

> **NOTE:** The `monkeyrunner` tool is not related to the `I/Application Exerciser Monkey`, also known as the `monkey` tool.  The `monkey` tool runs in an `adb shell` directly on the device or emulator and generates pseudo-random streams of user and system events. In comparison, the `monkeyrunner` tool controls devices and emulators from a workstation by sending specific commands and events from an API.